# Display a Div at top of page based on meta

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom function that states the status of the user in wordpress

```
 add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );

function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <h3><?php _e("Club Status", "blank"); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="status"><?php _e("Status"); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="status" id="status" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_user_meta( 'status', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e("User Status with Club"); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>


    </table>
<?php }

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( empty( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'update-user_' . $user_id ) ) {
        return;
    }
    
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { 
        return false; 
    }
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'status', $_POST['status'] );

}
```

This inserts it into the DB just fine.  I want to display IF the user is listed as PAST DUE a red banner at the top of page stating they are past due.

I tried

```
function add_conditional_div($content) {
    global $user;
    $meta_field = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'status', true);
    if ("Past Due" === $meta_field) {
        $content .= '<div>You are past due!</div>';
    }
    return $content;
}
```

The above shows no data anywhere.

Problem 2, in the edit of user profile, it is not keeping the new data there so we cant edit it after the fact.

Comment: Never use global $user. Use wp_get_current_user - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/ . As for not updating your field could be many reasons. Debug $_POST and see what data is passing.